# How do I find user by username rather than email in ruby on rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

I've tried a few things but can't seem to get my head round it. I've been practicing and know how to do this using email but how can I do it using username?

```
def self.authenticate(username, password)
    user = find_by_name(username)
    if user && user.password_hash ==  BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
    user
    else
      nil
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
user = find_by_name(username)
```

to

```
user = find_by_username(username)
```

Comment: Wow that simple. How does it do that? Does it add whatever attribute in question to find_by_? as I couldn't find this in the api doc

Comment: @Psychonetcs ActiveModel does some fancy work to map attributes of the model to additional methods on your model class.

Comment: Started to experience the benefits of using rails on another level now..thanks for your help.